# Are these a Tautology?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Are the following two well-formed formulae a tautology ?

1. $ \forall x\forall y P(x,y)\rightarrow \forall x\forall y P(y,x)    $
2. $[ \forall x\exists y (P(x,y) \rightarrow R(x,y) ) ] \leftrightarrow [ \forall x\exists y (\lnot P(x,y) \lor   R(x,y) ) ]$

According to me both are tautologies. But I had to make a choice between these two in an exam. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Perhaps you should be asking the instructor, not us.

Comment: Yes, they are tautologies, in the sense they are true in all $L$-structures for any suitable language.

Comment: The mention of *well-formed* makes me alert for the possibility that your instructor doesn't consider the second one to be well-formed.

Comment: There is no instructor. It's was an competitive exam. I cannot ask them .@GEdgar

Comment: @GitGud why do you think the 2nd one is not a well-formed formula ?

Comment: @AtulGangwar In the strictest sense it isn't because of the use of square brackets. Are you sure you were meant to pick only one?

Comment: Yes. It was a national level post-graduation exam. Though errors do creep in now and then and marks are awarded to all . 
And that square brackets is a nice catch(probably). The answers would be out in 1 month and then I would know what the instructor thinks. Thanks for input.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  what do you have to say about the accepted answer ?

Comment: In logic, perhaps a little more than elsewhere, the meaning of a word depends on choices made by the author/instructor. Some restrict the word to formulas of the propositional calculus. Some take the broad view that any first order sentence true in all appropriate $L$-structures is a tauology. There are intermediate choices! By the way, neither expression is a well formed formula. For example, the first is missing the outer parentheses one usually asks for. As the the answer, it is a careful explanation of a couple of the common meaning given to the term *tautology*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) :

> is a key concept in *propositional logic*, where a *tautology* is defined as a propositional formula that is true under any possible Boolean valuation of its propositional variables.

According to this definition, the formula :

> $∀x∀yP(x,y)→∀x∀yP(y,x)$

being a formula of first-order logic, is **not** a tautology, also if it is an (universally) *valid* formula of first-order logic indeed.

In another sense, we can say that a formula of first-order logic is a *tautology* when it is a *substitution instance* of a propositional formula which is a tautology; for example, the *valid* f-o formula $\forall xP(x) \to \forall xP(x)$ is obtained from $\varphi \rightarrow \varphi$ replacing $\varphi$ with the formula $\forall xP(x)$.

Neither in this second sense the above formula is a tautology, because it can be seen as an instance of the propositional formula $\varphi \to \psi$, which is not a tautology.

---

Regarding the formula :

> $∀x∃y(P(x,y)→R(x,y))↔∀x∃y(¬P(x,y)∨R(x,y))$

with the *tautological equivalence* : $(p \rightarrow q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot p \lor q)$ we can re-write it as :

> $∀x∃y(P(x,y)→R(x,y))↔∀x∃y(P(x,y)→R(x,y))$

and now it is a *substitution instance* of the tautology : $\varphi \leftrightarrow \varphi$.